How do I zoom-in on the channels in VSE?

It would seem to be a simple task, but no. I would like to have more channels visible in the sequencer tab. But if I zoom out, the channel just gets smaller, rather than showing more of them. Can you only have 7 channels visible at once?

While holding down Ctrl and your middle mouse button; move your mouse horizontally or vertically to scale your view in respective directions.
You can also drag the right-side scrollbar upwards - even when you reach the top, just keep dragging and you will eventually zoom out:


Thanks. I thought I had tried everything! I will accept as answer when it allows me to.

@JamesRiley Another option would be to drag the scrollbar on the right upwards - even when you reach the top, just keep dragging and you zoom out vertically: scrollbar

Oh yes that works well too. thanks

Shamelessly added Gordon's comment to my answer, thanks
